# When do skew symmetric and symmetric positive definite matricies commute?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, hamilton-equations

Let $J$ be a skew-symmetric matrix and $A$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix. When is it possible for $JA = AJ$?

Comment: Depends on where they work.